# Motherboard, sound and CD Drivers not working after initial boot

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound

I have booted up my new build yesterday with Ubunutu 12.04 and am having a few issues! I am new to Ubuntu so some advise would be appreciated.

Anyway, I managed to get everything up and running except for my soundcard, cd/dvd driver and motherboard wont accept the driver downloads.

Is there a way around this?

I have a

- RSI H87 G43 Socket 1150 ATX Motherboard
- Creative SoundBlaster Express X-Fi Titanium Fatal1ty Champion Pro Series

Any help would be much appreciated! This is my first home build PC and the fact it's up and running is a god send! Now I have Ubuntu too, I can't ask for much of a better week!! Just need those drivers....

Comment: I have also tried using Jockey_kde and this doesn't pick up anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading the linux driver from Creative and installing as-per instructions ? if so, what does it say when it fails ?

Also, have you tried booting from a livecd containing Ubuntu 13.04 to see if your sound card is supported out-of-the-box by the latest version ?

Comment: when downlaing the linux package the instructions say: Quick install

=============
In terminal,

1) Goto source directory
2) Execute make command as root
   make
   make install                                                      I can get on the termianl and get the source directory but then i dont really know what to do to be honest!! As my CD/DVD driver isn't being picked up either atm, I cant livecd boot anything, usb only atm, but im running Ubuntu 12.04, do you think I should upgrade to 13.04?